# helm chart deploy image from local repository

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubectl

i am trying to use local repository image in helm chart.

```
**
image: 
  repository: /root/back/test-image
  pullPolicy: Never
  tag: v1**
```

but it is throwing error.

```
Events:
  Type     Reason         Age               From               Message
  ----     ------         ----              ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled      31s               default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/mychart-v1-****-*** to localhost.localdomain
  Warning  InspectFailed  8s (x4 over 31s)  kubelet            Failed to apply default image tag "/root/backup/test-image:v1": couldn't parse image reference "/root/backup/test-image:v1": invalid reference format
  Warning  Failed         8s (x4 over 31s)  kubelet            Error: InvalidImageName
```

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean local repository? Looking at your example, looks like you have a docker image saved to disk at `/root/back/test-image`. You cannot reference docker images on disk as an "image". You need to "load" the image onto all the nodes and then you can provide the loaded image reference name as `image.repository` and set `image.pullPolicy: Never`

```
$ docker load < /root/back/test-image
Loaded image: my_test_image:v1     # example reference - might vary for your image
```

Provide the image reference from above output - `my_test_image:v1` as `image.repository` value.